# How to specify where to start in an itertools.cycle function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I need to cycle through a list for starting position between `1-4`
using `itertools` I am able to cycle through the list

```
positions = itertools.cycle([1,2,3,4])
next(positions)
```

This does return the next position, but what if the next time I need to start at 3? How can I set the start position?

I need the start position to change often, I cant just change the list to start at 3.

Comment: The start of a *running* `cycle`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't set a starting position; it'll always start where the given sequence starts.

You *can* move the cycle along a few steps before you use it for whatever you need it for. Use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip some items:

```
from itertools import islice

starting_at_three = islice(positions, 2, None)
```

You pass in the iterable, then a start and stop value; `None` here means that the `islice()` iterator continues forever or until the underlying `positions` iterator is exhausted.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import islice, cycle
>>> positions = cycle([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> starting_at_three = islice(positions, 2, None)
>>> next(starting_at_three)
3
>>> next(starting_at_three)
4
>>> next(starting_at_three)
1
```

The other option is to pass in a different sequence; you could pass in `[3, 4, 1, 2]` for example.

Comment: islice works for setting the starting postion, but if I keep using it like in the demo it starts it at the new index position, so in your example it would actually go: 

    >>> from itertools import islice, cycle
    >>> positions = cycle([1, 2, 3, 4])
    >>> starting_at_three = islice(positions, 2, None)
    >>> next(starting_at_three)
    3
    >>> next(starting_at_three)
    2
    >>> next(starting_at_three)
    1

Comment: @SierraKilo: That's demonstrably not true or even possible.

Comment: @SierraKilo: see https://repl.it/Fxvp/0 a live demo if you want to play with this some more.

Comment: @SierraKilo: last but not least, note that Willem's `position3` and my solutions are *exactly the same thing*.

Comment: @marijn pieters: yes, thanks I see its the same answer, I marked his correct because it came first.  The link to like demo is not working.  I must have done something wrong, it always returns the same value.  my mistake.

Comment: @SierraKilo: I fixed the link in my comment, not sure how that got corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.cycle#itertools.islice) for that:

```
from itertools import cycle
from itertools import islice

positions3 = islice(cycle([1,2,3,4]),2,None)
```

this will result in a generator that emits 3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...

In case the **start position `k` is large** (compared to the length of the original list), it can pay off to perform a modulo first:

```
from itertools import cycle
from itertools import islice

source_list = [1,2,3,4]
k = 10000000 # offset index
positions_k = islice(cycle(source_list),k%len(source_list),None)
```

This will generate an equivalent result, but `islice` will not drop the first 10M elements.

Comment: This works for setting the starting location, but to iterate through the rest of the list just use next(position)

Answer (score 0):

Use slices of the original list:

```
In [15]: def custom_slice(lst, start):
   ....:     return cycle(lst[start:] + lst[:start + 1])
```

Demo:

```
In [16]: positions = custom_slice(lst, 2)

In [17]: next(positions)
Out[17]: 3

In [18]: next(positions)
Out[18]: 4

In [19]: next(positions)
Out[19]: 1

In [20]: next(positions)
Out[20]: 2
```