# Python function to jump to the start value of an itertools iteration cycle

Tags: python, python-itertools, cycle

I have a python cycle that iterates to the next currency pair (ACTIVES) each time a function is called. Can anyone help with a code that can jump to the start of a cycle (in this case EURUSD) even when the iteration has not reached the end of the cycle and is at say (USDJPY)? Thank you. Here is my code:

```
# ACTIVES ITERATE FUNCTION
ACTIVES_alternator = cycle(('EURUSD','EURJPY','GBPUSD','USDJPY','GBPJPY','EURGBP'))
def iterate_action():
   global ACTIVES
   global ACTIVES_Alternator
   ACTIVES = next(ACTIVES_alternator)
   print("Next actives: ",ACTIVES)
# ACTIVES ITERATE FUNCTION
```

Comment: where is cycle? where is next?

Comment: Here is the cycle: ACTIVES_alternator = cycle(('EURUSD','EURJPY','GBPUSD','USDJPY','GBPJPY','EURGBP')) and next : ACTIVES = next(ACTIVES_alternator)

Answer (score 0):

This will cycle through ACTIVES_alternator but you have to provide the starting point...

```
# ACTIVES ITERATE FUNCTION
ACTIVES_alternator = ['EURUSD','EURJPY','GBPUSD','USDJPY','GBPJPY','EURGBP']
 
def iterate_action(actives_alternator, current_active):
    index = actives_alternator.index(current_active)+1
    if index > len(actives_alternator)-1:
        index = 0
    next_active = actives_alternator[index]
    print("Next actives: ", next_active)
    return next_active
# ACTIVES ITERATE FUNCTION
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_active = "EURUSD"
    while True:
       current_active = iterate_action(ACTIVES_alternator, current_active)
```

Output:

```
Next actives:  EURUSD
Next actives:  EURJPY
Next actives:  GBPUSD
Next actives:  USDJPY
Next actives:  GBPJPY
Next actives:  EURGBP
Next actives:  EURUSD
Next actives:  EURJPY
Next actives:  GBPUSD
Next actives:  USDJPY
Next actives:  GBPJPY
Next actives:  EURGBP
Next actives:  EURUSD
Next actives:  EURJPY
Next actives:  GBPUSD
Next actives:  USDJPY
Next actives:  GBPJPY
Next actives:  EURGBP
```

Edit:
Your code works just fine:

```
import itertoolet
# ACTIVES ITERATE FUNCTION
ACTIVES_alternator = itertools.cycle(('EURUSD','EURJPY','GBPUSD','USDJPY','GBPJPY','EURGBP'))
def iterate_action():
   global ACTIVES
   global ACTIVES_Alternator
   ACTIVES = next(ACTIVES_alternator)
   print("Next actives: ",ACTIVES)
   return ACTIVES
# ACTIVES ITERATE FUNCTION

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        current_active = iterate_action()
```

last edit:

```
from itertools import *

# ACTIVES ITERATE FUNCTION
ACTIVES_alternator = ['EURUSD','EURJPY','GBPUSD','USDJPY','GBPJPY','EURGBP']
ACTIVES_alternator_cycle = cycle(ACTIVES_alternator)
def iterate_action():
   ACTIVES = next(ACTIVES_alternator_cycle)
   print("Next actives: ",ACTIVES)
   return ACTIVES
# ACTIVES ITERATE FUNCTION

def incrementPos(current):
    current += 1
    if current > (len(ACTIVES_alternator)-1):
        current = 0 
    return current 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    currentPos = 0 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    currentPos = incrementPos(currentPos) 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    currentPos = incrementPos(currentPos) 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    currentPos = incrementPos(currentPos) 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    ACTIVES_alternator_cycle = islice(ACTIVES_alternator_cycle, (len(ACTIVES_alternator)-1) - currentPos, None)
    currentPos = 0 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    currentPos = incrementPos(currentPos) 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    currentPos = incrementPos(currentPos) 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    ACTIVES_alternator_cycle = islice(ACTIVES_alternator_cycle, (len(ACTIVES_alternator)-1) - currentPos, None)
    currentPos = 0 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    currentPos = incrementPos(currentPos) 
    current_active = iterate_action()
    ACTIVES_alternator_cycle = islice(ACTIVES_alternator_cycle, (len(ACTIVES_alternator)-1) - currentPos, None)
    currentPos = 0
```

output:

```
Next actives:  EURUSD
Next actives:  EURJPY
Next actives:  GBPUSD
Next actives:  USDJPY
Next actives:  EURUSD
Next actives:  EURJPY
Next actives:  GBPUSD
Next actives:  EURUSD
Next actives:  EURJPY
```

Comment: Hello Herlas, my code is already doing this. it starts again from the start when the cycle has reached the end. what if i want to jump to EURUSD lets say when the cycle is at GBPUSD? this is what i want to achieve

Comment: then your code works just fine...

Comment: Instead of while True you could look for a key pressed and if it is then do whatever and if required then afterwards continue the cycle. There are various modules you can look up which detect key presses.

Comment: `while true` was only for demonstrative purpose to show that next() works

Comment: My code works fine @A.Herlas but what i need is a code to reset the position to start anytime i want it to

Comment: you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459582/how-to-specify-where-to-start-in-an-itertools-cycle-function

Comment: I have update -> last edit: